# split big xml file to multiple files that contains eg. 100 elements in java

Tags: java, xml

hello every one i have a very big challenge tody  , is to split a big xml file that contains for example 2000 elements (eg) :

```
   `<bigxml>
    <element><small>AAA<small/><small>BBB<small/><small>CCC<small/></element>
    <element><small>DDD<small/><small>EEE<small/><small>FFF<small/></element>
    <element><small>GGG<small/><small>HHH<small/><small>III<small/></element>
    .......
    .......
   </bigxml>`
```

the result is multiple files with 100 element per file without losing the header

```
'<bigxml>    </bigxml>' per file !
```

how to proceede please ?

Comment: Start by taking a read through [Java API for XML Processing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/)

Comment: ok thanks MadProgrammer

Answer (score 0):

Well, the simplest thing to do is to read the file line by line and have a counter to make sure that when you read 100 lines, write it into a file with opening and closing `bigxml` tag and continue iteration. A simple nested loop should do the trick.

Do something like

```
while(scanner.hasNextLine()){
    // Here open a new file 
    for(int i=0;i<100;i++){
         String s = scanner.nextLine();
        // write string into the file
    }
    // Close the file
}
```

Comment: ok thaks for your reply ,and i'll do it by DOM or SAX or if you know another framework to simplify the work ? thanks again .

Comment: DOM and SAX parsers are used to parse the xml file to get individual elements or attributes from them, and using them here would only make the process more complex...Since you just want to split the file based on lines, this would be the simplest way

Comment: all right , because i was writing dom an sax and yes  it was very complex .

Comment: @anirddh : can you please give a demo ?

Comment: another issue is that if the file is not well formed like :  '<bigxml>
    <element><small>AAA<small/><small>BBB<small/><small>CCC<small/></element>
    <element><small>DDD<small/><small>EEE<small/><small>FFF<small/></element>
    <element><small>GGG<small/><small>HHH<small/><small>III<small/></element>' but in another format the algorithm will not work correctly ? what to do ?

Comment: You mean if each element is not in a single line??

Comment: In that case, you just read the entire file into a string first, use `replaceAll()` to replace each `</element>` with `</element>\n` and then use that string

Comment: Please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/326390/how-to-create-a-java-string-from-the-contents-of-a-file to read file contents into a string and then look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html?is-external=true to know how to use the `replaceAll()` method. try and understand the java docs, as this will help you become a better programmer.